# How can I configure iptables to forward and forget?

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2, iptables, linux-networking

I'm trying to create a front controller where users can connect to a specific port and have their connection redirected to a different IP/port.  The reason I'd like to be able to do this is for statistical reasons, since I would like to parse the log files later to see how many connections have been made to specific game servers (which I do not have access to) so I can adjust the 'popularity' ranks of each server based on the amount of connections it received.

I've managed to achieve this by using the follow iptables command:

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <PORT> -j DNAT --to <DEST_IP>:<DEST_PORT>`

This will divert:
`<IP>:<PORT>` to a remote host `<DEST_IP>:<DEST_PORT>`.

Example:
`mycoolserverdirectory.com:23456` -> `somebodyscoolserver:25500`

(Each server would be configured to listen on a unique port number).

The problem is, the connection seems to be reliant on the original `<IP>`, since I noticed shutting down the Ec2 instance will cause the redirected connection(s) to terminate.

I'd like to be able to forward the connection permanently and forget about the original connection once a connection has been forwarded.  Thus acting like a 'router' rather than a proxy.

**Note:** I had considered using AWS Route 53 for this (using SRV records).  Although I would be able to redirect the connection, it appears retrieving logs/stats isn't possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, the client goes directly to you're server as their endpoint. If your server goes offline you expect this not to happen?

Comment: Yeah.  Basically I'd like, if possible, to use redirect the connection to the new host/ip.  The same way a HTTP 301 would work in a browser, but at a network level.  I'm not a network engineer so I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I thought I would ask.

Comment: This isn't possible at the level you are asking, as the destination (and the route to get there) are already setup. You can do some tricks with `vrrp` to provide some high availability. Or using a transparent proxy / router like you mentioned, but that isn't feasible unless you can force all traffic through your server as a route.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the specific game servers (which are EC2 instances?) and thus aren't able to assign a static IP (Elastic IP in AWS lingo) to them then you need to be able to detect a change to the IP addresses and refresh the appropriate iptables rule when that happens (DNS names are only resolved when a rule is first loaded).

You could use a cron job similar to one here (I'm not crazy about this python code, but a search for "iptables dynamic DNS" should give some more ideas:

http://diginc.us/linux/2010/using-iptables-with-dynamic-ip-hostnames-like-dyndns-org/

(Note that the iptables manpage states that using hostnames is a "really bad idea" but I don't see how rewriting the rules using an IP from the results of a DNS query is any different, anyway you're working with outbound connections, not permitting inbound).

As far as logging, in iptables the typical practice is to add a matching rule with a LOG destination before the rule in question:

Personally, I'd create a separate chain for each server you want to redirect to:

```
iptables -t nat -N chain_gameserver1
iptables -t nat -A chain_gameserver1 -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "Gameserver 1 new connection"
iptables -t nat -A chain_gameserver1 -j DNAT --to gameserver1.wherever.com:<port>
```

And then have the cron that checks for IP changes to gameserver1 just flush and reload chain_gameserver1 rather than all your tables.